# mod_wsgi unable to connect WSGI daemon process

Tags: django, cpanel, mod-wsgi

I am using Easy apache 4, mod_wsgi, and Python 3.5.  When I called a Django project in the server I got the following error:

```
(13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=24223): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon
process 'user123' on '/var/run/wsgi.8442.6.7.sock' as user with uid=3708.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Apache installation is likely set up to run with `SECURE` privileges mode. This means that the Apache child worker process is forked and privileges dropped before handling the request, which in this case is simply trying to proxy the request through to the mod_wsgi daemon process. The consequence of this is that it cannot connect to the socket for the daemon process, as it was setup with ownership to match the original Apache child worker process before privileges were dropped.

This is evident because the error message has `uid` in the range of a normal user and not the special `apache` or `nobody` user.

To fix it, you need to modify the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive configuration and add the option:

```
socket-user=#3708
```

or:

```
socket-user=username
```

where `username` is replaced with the actual name of the user with `uid` of `3708`.

The addition of this option seems to be required due to recent changes in CPanel configurations for Apache.

Comment: I'm getting this error with uid=33 (www-data) if running service apache2 reload, but not if running service apache2 restart. Is that indicating something bad or is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime **socket-user** setting does not work.
This may occur because of **WSGISocketPrefix** path not found

- If it is VPS:

  WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
- If you are in a shared hosting:

  WSGISocketPrefix ../../var/run/wsgi

Thank You

Comment: As per comment on your answer elsewhere, why a relative path. It is magic you probably need to explain.

Comment: The path/var/run/ user123 do not have access to that folder.Only root and approved users have. So we need to show a path for wsgi socket.
@GrahamDumpleton Sir do I need to explain more?I will if it is not

Comment: Your proposed solution though doesn't actually help with what the question was about. The only solution for when ``SECURE`` privileges mode is used, as was the case here, is that ``socket-user`` option. Your answer is dealing with a separate problem, which is the default runtime directory on some Linux distros is not accessible to the Apache user. This separate issue is described in the mod_wsgi documentation at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-issues.html#location-of-unix-sockets

Comment: yes @GrahamDumpleton thank you for the clarification. I will keep both in mind next time.Actually I was trying to add in the answer the other way also.You are correct